# When is it appropriate to indent a paragraph?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm working on a short novel and I was wondering when it is appropriate for me to indent my paragraphs. Is it when I start a new paragraph? Is it when a new subject occurs(as in storyline)? Does this include dialogue? Does it just depend on what I'm writing?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of indentation you're talking about? There are styles where a paragraph is indicated by indenting the first line. There are also styles where other typesetting techniques are employed (e.g. line spacing), and indentation is employed for other purposes.

Comment: Paragraph indentation is a part of book design. The content is not the issue. Sometimes the first paragraph of a chapter or a section is flush left, sometimes not.